# Is there a better explanation of Hellman's paper on rainbow tables than the paper itself?

Tags: reference-request, cr.crypto-security, cryptographic-attack

I'm reading through Hellman's [A Cryptanalytic Time-Memory Trade-off](http://www-ee.stanford.edu/~hellman/publications/36.pdf) [PDF], and I was wondering if there is code out there that implements this or if there are better explanations of how a password could be decrypted using rainbow table method mentioned in this paper?

Comment: I don't think asking for code fits the scope of this website -- but since I'm aware of something relevant: http://project-rainbowcrack.com/ . They mention [another paper](http://lasecwww.epfl.ch/php_code/publications/search.php?ref=Oech03) however.